# Poisson distribution of insects laying eggs.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Insects of a certain type lay eggs on leaves such that the number of
>   eggs on a given leaf has a Poisson distribution with mean $1$. For any
>   given leaf, the probability is $0.1$ that it will be visited by such
>   an insect, and leaves are visited independently of each other.
>
> **(a)** What is the probability that a given leaf has no eggs?
>
> **(b)** If a leaf is inspected and has no eggs, what is the probability that it has been visited by an insect?
>
> **(c)** If 10 leaves are inspected and none have any eggs, what is the probability that at least one leaf has been visited by an insect?

Let $X=\{\text{Number of eggs on a given leaf}\}$ and we have that $X\sim \text{Poi}(\lambda), \ \lambda=1.$ We also know that $P(\text{Visit}) = 0.1.$ We are looking for $P(\text{No eggs}).$

So, according to Baye's theorem: $$P(\text{No eggs})=1-P(\text{Eggs})=1-P(\text{Eggs|Visit})\cdot P(\text{Visit})=1-0.1\cdot P(\text{Eggs|Visit}).$$

I have to find $$P(\text{Eggs|Visit})=\frac{e^{-1}(-1)^0}{0!}=\frac{1}{e}\approx 0.3679.$$

So

$$P(\text{No eggs})=1-0.1\cdot0.3679=0.9632.$$

Correct answer is $0.9 + 0.1\cdot e^{-1}\approx0.94.$

**Questions:**

**1)** In a problem, what is the main indicator that Baye's theorem should be used?

**2)** I don't really understand how it suffices to directly use the pmf for Possion distribution to compute $P(\text{No eggs}).$ My random variable $X$ only counts ne number of eggs on a leaf, not number of eggs *given a visitor*. I think this has something to do with getting incorrect answer.

Comment: Seriously, how do you know that $Y\sim Poi(\lambda p)$ and that $Y|X=x\sim Bin(x,p)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What you have computed as $1/e$ is $P[\text{No eggs|Visit}]$.
2. The probability of no eggs is: Probability of no visit + Probability[visit] $\times$ (Probability of no eggs given visit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate your answers? 1) Where in my application of Baye's have I gone wrong? 2) How can you deduce that?

Comment: Your statement in number two can't be true since $P(\text{No visit})=0.9$ and $P(\text{No eggs|Visit})=1/e$ so $0.9+0.3679 > 1.$

Comment: The Bayes rule application is fine; I've edited my answer.